# sliding effect from both side to center in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two images, and i want to slide both of them from both side(right & left) to meet at center. I am using jquery. But if the resolution of screen will changed then it affect on sliding. So what is the solution for this. And after reached at center i also want to show four other images but it could not getting. Below is my html code,

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>animate demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    position: absolute;

  }
  </style>
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="block"><img src="Left-Logo.png"  border="0" style="float: left;"/></div>
 <div class="block2"><img src="Right-Logo.png"  border="0" style="float: right;"/></div>
 <div class="block3"><img src="pic1.png"  border="0" style="visibility: hidden;"/></div>
 <div class="block4"><img src="pic2.png"  border="0" style="visibility: hidden;"/></div>
 <div class="block5"><img src="pic3.png"  border="0" style="visibility: hidden;"/></div>
 <div class="block6"><img src="pic4.png"  border="0" style="visibility: hidden;"/></div>


<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "+=12.1%" }, 5000 );
});

$( document ).ready(function(){
  $( ".block2" ).animate({ "right": "+=12.1%" }, 5000 );
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".block3" ).show();
  $( ".block4" ).show();
  $( ".block5" ).show();
  $( ".block6" ).show();

});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are calling `document ready` 3 times?

Comment: without it how it be called? @Tambo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a separate library seems like overkill to me...I made a quick jsfiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/c42rkf07/

JS is pretty much the same...With a few css extras:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".block1").animate({"left": "+=50%"}, 5000 );
  $(".block2").animate({"right": "+=50%"}, 5000 );
});
```

Worth reading up a bit more on js, as you don't need all those document ready statements as Tambo said...Good luck, keep at it! :)

Comment: But when i increasing size then it not coming from the exactly right or left side. It comes from some margin length from both side. And please give some explanation for four images will shown after both images reached at center. @Oli C

Comment: Yupp. Its working.Thanks @Oli C. kindly suggest something about how to display some images after that two images reached at center.

Comment: You need to pass in a function to fade in other elements, then it will only be run once others are complete: http://jsfiddle.net/c42rkf07/2/

Answer (score 0):

try [WOW slider](http://wowslider.com/) for getting desired effect.
No need of coding. Everything can be customized in UI.

Comment: I think this is for sliding panel, like to show images. But i want just two images sliding from both end of screen to center. @Ram